# How do I use an interviewer's name during an interview?

Tags: interviewing

I have little experience interviewing. I recently got an interview and the interviewer provided me with her name. How do I use her name throughout the interview?

Comment: This is going to be somewhat culture and industry specific. Could you add a location and industry to your question?

Comment: In an interview, it can't hurt to be a little more formal than normal. In the US that would mean Mr/Mrs.X or Dr.X if they are an academic. IMO very unlikely excessive formailty would be held against you at all in this stage.

Comment: @random person, In the US technology and computer sector, if you are an engineer or intern, then both the interviewers and the interviewees usually address one another by their first names even if they have the Ph.D or are the directors or VPs. Certainly, we can do that in a professional and respectful way. However, the way you call the interviewers may be different in other industries and countries. In general, you still can be a little more formal if you wish regardless of the industries or countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, be as formal in the interview as your interviewers are to you. If they address you as "Mrs. Person" (or whatever you title is), then address them as "Mrs. Interviewer". If they address you as "Random", address them as "Arbitrary" (or whatever their first name is).

Comment: Should I address them when answering a question?

Comment: Well, I certainly wouldn't suggest ignoring them.

Comment: _..address them as "Mrs. Interviewer"_ -> Mrs. would imply that she is married, I'd suggest 'Madam' instead - thats more neutral than "Mrs“, „Miss“ or „Ms“ ..

Comment: @iLuvLogix "or whatever their title is"; "Mrs" is just a placeholder here. "Madam" would be *massively* overformal in any company I've ever worked in.